# What's the fluid-icon meta tag for?

Tags: meta-tags, favicon, icon

I've stumbled across an HTML meta tag I didn't know and wondered what it is for:

```
<link rel="fluid-icon" href="https://github.com/fluidicon.png" title="GitHub" />
```

I googled around, but couldn't find any explanation. What is this? A new favicon approach? And what's the difference to the one I already know:

```
<link rel="icon" href="images/2/mail_icon_32.png" sizes="32x32"> 
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="https://www.google.com/a/scoop-gmbh.de/images/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

[Fluid](http://fluidapp.com/) is a way of running web applications as if they were native Mac apps. The fluid icon is the one that displays on the Mac in the dock.

Comment: And what size is it supposed to be? E.g. in OQ the beknownst way of providing a favicon in a PNG format has `sizes` attribute, to know this.

Answer (score 0):

As an additional information to @paulmorriss answer:

The icon should be of size 512x512

Source: https://www.flickr.com/groups/fluid_icons/